# Sklearn: Linear Regression with Polyfeature yields shapes not aligned

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I want to use the `Linear Regression` and `Poly Features` in `sklearn` to predict the y value of 100 data points, namely `np.linspace(0, 10, 100)`.

**Data:**

```
n = 15
x = np.linspace(0,10,n) + np.random.randn(n)/5
y = np.sin(x)+x/6 + np.random.randn(n)/10
```

OK, so what I have done so far actually works out fine with normal `Linear Regression`, but when I try to use `Polynomial Features` to try out some new models, it doesn't work out well.

**This works out fine:**

```
pre_result = []
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, random_state=0)
linreg = LinearRegression().fit(X_train.reshape(-1, 1), y_train)
pre_result.append(linreg.predict(np.linspace(0, 10, 100).reshape(-1, 1)))
```

**This produces an error:**

```
third = PolynomialFeatures(degree=3)
X_third = third.fit_transform(x.reshape(-1, 1))
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_third, y, random_state=0)
polyreg = LinearRegression().fit(X_train, y_train)
pre_result.append(polyreg.predict(np.linspace(0, 10, 100).reshape(-1, 1)))
```

**Error:**

```
ValueError: shapes (100,1) and (4,) not aligned: 1 (dim 1) != 4 (dim 0)
```

And if I use `PolynomialFeatures(degree=6)` instead of `degree=3`, it will show `ValueError: shapes (100,1) and (7,) not aligned: 1 (dim 1) != 7 (dim 0)`. This totally confuses me.

**Nonetheless, the following example runs just as fine:**

```
X_F1, y_F1 = make_friedman1(n_samples = 100,
                       n_features = 7, random_state=0)
poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=2)
X_F1_poly = poly.fit_transform(X_F1)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_F1_poly, y_F1,
                                               random_state = 0)
linreg = LinearRegression().fit(X_train, y_train)
predict = linreg.predict(X_test)
```

Appreciate if anyone provides any insight on this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the last line of your snippet. Here

```
polyreg.predict(np.linspace(0, 10, 100).reshape(-1, 1))
```

where you pass some "raw" inputs -  of the `x` variable: something with shape `(100,1)`.  This means you have 100 observations, each of which has one variable.

Your model (`polyreg`) expects each observation to have 4 variables (the coefficients of a 3rd degree polynomial).

### Solution 1

You could do this:

```
polyreg.predict( third.transform( np.linspace(0, 10, 100).reshape(-1, 1) ))
```

### Probably better solution:

But probably better is the approach in [this example](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_underfitting_overfitting.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-model-selection-plot-underfitting-overfitting-py) which uses a [`Pipeline`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html)

```
poly3_model = Pipeline(
    [('poly', PolynomialFeatures(degree=3)), 
     ('linear', LinearRegression())])

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x.reshape(-1, 1), y.reshape(-1, 1), random_state=0)

poly3_model.fit( X_train, y_train )
test_prediction = poly3_model.predict( X_test )
another_prediction = poly3_model.predict( np.linspace(0, 10, 100).reshape(-1, 1))
```